# How to set the background of a RelativeLayout the camera?

Tags: android

In my application, I have this layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I set the background of the base RelativeLayout layout to be the camera view?

Comment: I mean the camera of the device, I want the layout to show the camera, but instead of opening the camera, I want to have it's image in the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your root view a SurfaceView:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <SurfaceView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <fragment
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your code, open the camera and output the preview to your `SurfaceView`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();

    surfaceHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        private Camera mCamera;
        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            mCamera = Camera.open();

            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                                   int height) {
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, where should I set the surfaceView, I didn't get how should my xml look like

Comment: @Carmine The xml code I posted, is everything that you need in your xml file.

Comment: but how should i add my map fragment on it?

Comment: @Carmine How would that even look like? Camera preview behind a map?

Comment: yeah, i want my activity to be the camera view, and a little map view in the right bottom part of the screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65001/discussion-between-carmine-and-user3249477).